# Calling an ActiveRecord association method from an array in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, excel, activerecord, associations

Goal: Produce an Excel document with information from 3 associated models that is similar to that in my HTML table. The to_xls gem requires this as a list of arrays.

https://github.com/splendeo/to_xls

Desired output:

```
(working for both)      (working for both)    (working in HTML, not in Excel)
territory.branch.name    territory.zip    territory.mailedcounts.maximum(:maileddate)
My Branch                90210            2012-05-01
My Branch                90211            2012-05-03
My Branch                90212
```

A Branch has many Territories.
A Territory has many Mailedcounts.

I can bring up the correct data in my view via the built in ActiveRecord methods for show.html.erb

```
<% for territory in @territories %>
<tr>
  <td><%= territory.branch.name %></td>      
  <td><%= territory.zip %></td>
  <td><%= territory.mailedcounts.maximum(:maileddate) %></td>
</tr>
<% end >
```

This is what I have correctly exporting so far

```
class BranchesController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
 def show
  @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
  @territories = @branch.territories

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls { 
      send_data @territories.to_xls(:columns => [ { :branch => :name }, :zip ] )
    }
 end
end
```

Which gives me territory.branch.name and territory.zip which both work properly. Starting from territory I can't figure out how to get at my mailedcounts info though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that did it for me. (After far more hours of trying than it should have taken.)

The trick was to define a class in the Mailedcount model, not the Territory model.

```
class Mailedcount < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
.
  belongs_to :branch
  belongs_to :territory

  class << self
    def max_maileddate
      maximum('maileddate')
    end
  end
end
```

Back to the controller I can now call that method.

```
class BranchesController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
 def show
  @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
  @territories = @branch.territories

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xls { 
    send_data @territories.to_xls(:columns => [ { :branch => :name }, :zip,
                        { :mailedcounts => :max_maileddate } ] )
  }
    end
  end
```

I couldn't get a scope or method to work in the Territory model without essentially reproducing the relationship with another join.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom scope should work for this.

```
class Territory < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :mailed_counts_max_date, lambda {
    mailcounts.maximum(:maileddate)  
  }
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
class BranchesController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
  @territories = @branch.territories

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls { 
      send_data @territories.to_xls(:columns => [ { :branch => :name }, :zip, :mailed_counts_max_date ] )
    }
 end
end
```

Comment: Very nice. I could use this to get logic out of my controllers and view too. (Like a civilized person.) Running into a stupid error right now, will try again tomorrow.

Comment: I noticed that you had a mix of "mailedcounts" and "mailcounts" ... possibly the cause of your bug?

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris, you got me pointed in the right direction. The syntax you have for creating the scope by calling the built in ActiveRecord association method was giving me a no method defined error. Unsure if this is by design or if I messed something up. It looks like a scope or class within the Territory model is the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (totally untested)

```
format.xls {
  # essentially replicate what the view does
  arr = []
  for territory in @territories
    arr << [territory.branch.name, territory.zip,  territory.mailedcounts.maximum(:maileddate)] 
  end
  send_data arr.to_xls
}
```

If it (the gem?) expects a list of arrays, theres nothing sacrosanct about using ActiveRecord...

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I couldn't quite get this to work which was disappointing just because of the extra flexibility it would have given me. Every time I got close something deep within the to_xls gem would complain.